# Please explain this syntax for an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

```
10    const handle_request = (req) => {
20        req.command = "do something";
30        Addr = req.payload.addr;
40    };

60    request_handler = handle_request;
```

req seems to an internal variable but it's not included by the calling relation of line 60 and it appears no where else in the code. What does = (req) => do?

thanks

Comment: What Javascript reference are you using?

Comment: Line 60 doesn't call `handle_request`. It merely assigns the function object to another variable.

Comment: For a few seconds I thought this was BASIC.

Answer (score 0):

Without using the ES6 syntax, that function would look like this

```
function handle_request(req) {
    req.command = "do something";
    Addr = req.payload.addr;
}
```

Comment: Makes way more sense, but I guess the other is required for a variable assignment?

Comment: @michaelm700: No. Function *expressions* have existed since the beginning: `const handle_request = function() { ... }`. It doesn't matter anyway, the result is the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

(req) =>  creates a function without name that takes parameter named req. After => goes body of the function with it's scope.
These function called arrow function expression and you can read more about it here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions